# cannot configure oracle 12c on windows 10

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I recently installed Oracle 12c on my system on windows10.
Created an instance with `dbca` and named it as `orcl`.

On `sqlplus " /as sysdba"`
I get connected to an idle instance. So I executed `startup`.

Now I get error

```
SQL> startup
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file 
'C:\ORACLE12C\12C\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\INITORCL.ORA'
```

I checked the path, the Initorcl file does not exist at the path.

Tried `create pfile='path/initorcl.ora' from spfile='path/init.ora'`

but get an error `file size mismatch`

What is the next step to get this configured?

Answer (score 0):

`init.ora` is actually your pfile (not spfile). Theoretically you could try `startup pfile='path/init.ora';` and that should work.

You can either rename `init.ora` to `initORCL.ora` (not sure if the SID is case sensitive in Windows), or create an spfile from your `init.ora` file:

`create spfile='path/spfileORCL.ora' from pfile='path/init.ora'`

Comment: tried `startup pfile="C:/Oracle12c/12c/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/init.ora " ` ,  i got this error                                                                                 `SQL> startup "C:/Oracle12c/12c/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/init.ora"
SP2-0714: invalid combination of STARTUP options
SQL> startup pfile="C:/Oracle12c/12c/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/init.ora";
ORA-01261: Parameter db_recovery_file_dest destination string cannot be translated
ORA-01263: Name given for file destination directory is invalid
OSD-04018: Unable to access the specified directory or device.`

Comment: created `spfile` as you mentioned . File was created. On `startup` , i got the error `SQL> startup
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00123: invalid character 0 found in the input file
SQL>`

Comment: Are you positive that's the right path to your init.ora file? dbs folder is usually Unix/linix location. In Windows it's a database folder.

Comment: Oh interesting. Wonder if your init.ora file is corrupt. Have you tried opening it? I'd start there, make sure it's readable, and check all the parameters for any oddities.